# How to use a panel created inside a .fig file by other different .fig file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two distinct files, myguide.fig (and its corresponding mygui.m) which contains the definition of an uitabgroup and the file caract.fig (and its corresponding caract.m) which contains a panel. I call the file caract.m from the file myguide.m and obtain the handle of the panel. Then I change the Parent property of the panel to assign it to one of the tabs of the uitabgroup. I only achieve that this works (setting the Visibility Property of caract.fig off) the first time I run myguide. If I try to run it a second time, I get the error message “Invalid handle object” for the handle of the panel returned. I do not understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained here:

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives/

Related articles:

- http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitab-customizations/
- http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitab-colors-icons-images/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It made me to change the question which I had formulated in a wrong and unprecise way.

Comment: Take a look at http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/ together with the built-in ***struct2handle*** function

Comment: I think you should edit your answer and write the correct solution.